# Synchronize multiple cameras to boost frame rate

Tags: opencv, frame-rate

I've been reading around a bit about reading frames from multiple cameras but it seems everywhere people are trying to grab frames from multiple cameras at the same time for different purposes (like stereoscopy) but I couldn't find a way to grab frames at slightly different times to produce a combined video stream with boosted frame rate.

In general this could seem a rather dangerous enterprise but my setup is quite peculiar so I can easily realign the frames with each other: the cameras and the stage are almost perfectly perpendicular and quite near to each other, and the stage is actually a flat surface so basically parallax is not an issue.

I've read around about using OpenCV and multiple threads (though I suspect I don't need threads because of the sequential nature of the process). Is there anyone that already tried to do something like this? FTR, my cameras are three PS3 Eye, and I need both high resolution (VGA) and high frame rate (one camera gives 30 fps at VGA resolution under Linux).

Comment: It looks like you have to write the driver yourself... OpenCV definitely will not help you here. You can try to research some camera SDK, but such accurate timing is usually not available for regular users, especially for cheap cameras. If you need high quality, a proffesional high-framerate camera is usually the solution

Comment: I thought so. Unfortunately we don't have a budget for a professional camera. I used to work with an AVT Marlin fitted with custom lens, at my previous workplace, which summed up to about 1200 €: definitely not feasible. Anyway, thanks for your comment, I'll keep looking and, if necessary, I'll have a bunch of undergrads write the driver :)

Comment: You can't. A camera that would have hardware support for such precise timings would be very expensive and could probably offer a high frame rate already. Quality comes at a price, and if you need it, you'd better convince your boss to find the money